# How to get data from grpc Status.details field after StatusException in Java / Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, grpc, grpc-java

I have grpc server.
It sends rich errors in Status.details, like it recommends [there](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/status.proto)

Ruch error described in proto file

```
message Error {
  Code code = 1;
  // user friendly text
  string message = 2;
}
```

grpcurl response:

```
ERROR:
  Code: FailedPrecondition
  Message: device blocked
  Details:
  1)    {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/myapp.overall.v1.Error",
          "code": "CODE_DEVICE_BLOCKED",
          "message": "Выполнение операции невозможно тк вашего устройства отправляется слишком много запросов. Пожалуйста попробуйте еще раз чере 3 минуты"
        }
```

How i can access to Status.details with Kotlin / Java (Android) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`StatusProto.fromThrowable(Throwable)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/protobuf/StatusProto.html#fromThrowable-java.lang.Throwable-) to convert to a `google.rpc.Status` proto:

```java
import io.grpc.protobuf.StatusProto;

com.google.rpc.Status status = StatusProto.fromThrowable(statusException);
for (Any any : status.getDetailsList()) {
  if (!any.is(Error.class)) {
    continue;
  }
  Error error = any.unpack(Error.class);
  // error is now available
}
```

You can make a utility to make that less verbose.

Comment: I cant import io.grpc.protobuf.StatusProto, because it does not exists. 
I guess that grpc-protobuf-lite (which uses for android) does not contains this class. 
Any ideas how to add this class to my project?

Comment: Temporary solution: do not use lite version. 
Looking for better solution

Comment: See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6554#issuecomment-567653077 for a workaround. You'd need to depend on grpc-protobuf but then exclude the normal protobuf-java dependency in favor of protobuf-javalite. Obviously "not supported," but grpc-java won't go out-of-its-way to break it. The problem was also discussed at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7179